# how to use join in the query to fetch data from multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT   dates,
             SUM(Total_Likes) AS Total_likes,
             SUM(Real_Like) AS Real_Like,
             SUM(Secret_like) AS Secret_like
    FROM
    (
     SELECT  CAST(added_datetime AS DATE) AS dates,
          SUM(IF(like_flag=1,1,-1)) AS Total_Likes,

         ( 
             SELECT SUM(IF(like_flag=1,1,-1)) 
             FROM like_message_audit_log la
             WHERE  user_profile_type=1 AND CAST(added_datetime AS DATE)= '2017-07-21'
             AND    like_mode IN(1,2) 
             GROUP BY user_profile_id_fk
              ) AS Real_Like,
          (

           SELECT SUM(IF(like_flag=1,1,-1)) 
           FROM like_message_audit_log la
           WHERE  user_profile_type=2 AND CAST(added_datetime AS DATE)= '2017-07-21'
           AND    like_mode IN(1,2) 
           GROUP BY user_profile_id_fk
           )AS Secret_like

       FROM like_message_audit_log la
       WHERE  CAST(added_datetime AS DATE)= '2017-07-21'
       AND    like_mode IN(1,2) 
    )AS t
     GROUP BY dates;
```

above query run only for one date but i want to run it for date range between two dates
how to write that query please suggest

output of above query like is:
dates        Total_likes     Real_Like  Secret_like
2017-07-21    16               15             1

I rewrite above query like:

```
      SELECT  dates,
   SUM(Total_Likes) AS Total_likes,
    SUM(real_likes_count) AS Real_Like,
    SUM(secret_likes_count) AS Secret_like
    FROM
    (
  SELECT 
        CAST(added_datetime AS DATE) AS Dates,
        like_mode AS modes,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN like_flag=1 THEN 1 END) AS Total_Likes,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN like_flag=1 AND user_profile_type=1 THEN 1 END) AS real_likes_count,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN like_flag=1 AND user_profile_type=2 THEN 1 END) AS secret_likes_count
    FROM like_message_audit_log la
    WHERE added_datetime IN 
            (   SELECT MAX(lb.added_datetime) AS added_datetime
                FROM like_message_audit_log lb
                WHERE la.user_profile_id_fk=la.user_profile_id_fk AND lb.message_unique_id_fk=la.message_unique_id_fk
                GROUP BY user_profile_id_fk, message_unique_id_fk
            )
    GROUP BY CAST(added_datetime AS DATE) 


    )AS t

    WHERE dates BETWEEN '2017-07-21' AND '2017-08-04'
      AND    modes IN(1,2) 
   GROUP BY  Dates
   ORDER BY  Dates DESC;
```

this query works but take too much time
can i optimize above query

Comment: try googleing `between`

Comment: Those `SELECT SUM(...)` subqueries won't work. When you use a `SELECT` as a value, it has to return a single row.

Comment: @Barmar Perfect one..!!

Comment: @Barmar thats why i want query which select data of date ranges provided but in above subquery i can not use because then it will return multiple rows

Comment: @Barmar Have you checked my answer???

Comment: Using `CAST()` on a column will prevent using the index, that could be part of the performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

```
 SELECT   dates,
             SUM(Total_Likes) AS Total_likes,
             SUM(Real_Like) AS Real_Like,
             SUM(Secret_like) AS Secret_like
    FROM
    (
     SELECT  CAST(added_datetime AS DATE) AS dates,
          SUM(IF(like_flag=1,1,-1)) AS Total_Likes,

         ( 
             SELECT SUM(IF(like_flag=1,1,-1)) 
             FROM like_message_audit_log la
             WHERE  user_profile_type=1 AND CAST(added_datetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2017-07-21' AND '2017-07-27'
             AND    like_mode IN(1,2) 
             GROUP BY user_profile_id_fk
              ) AS Real_Like,
          (

           SELECT SUM(IF(like_flag=1,1,-1)) 
           FROM like_message_audit_log la
           WHERE  user_profile_type=2 AND CAST(added_datetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2017-07-21' AND '2017-07-27'
           AND    like_mode IN(1,2) 
           GROUP BY user_profile_id_fk
           )AS Secret_like

       FROM like_message_audit_log la
       WHERE  CAST(added_datetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2017-07-21' AND '2017-07-27'
       AND    like_mode IN(1,2) 
    )AS t
     GROUP BY dates;
```

Comment: Probably need to change all the subqueries as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT added_datetime,user_profile_id_fk,
SUM(CASE WHEN user_profile_type=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Real_Like,
SUM(CASE WHEN user_profile_type=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Secret_like,
SUM(1) AS Total_likes
FROM like_message_audit_log la
WHERE  CAST(added_datetime AS DATE) BETWEEN '2016-07-21' AND '2018-07-21'
AND    like_mode IN(1,2) 
GROUP BY user_profile_id_fk,added_datetime
```

You can check this [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65d160/2)

You can try above query. I think this is optimized way.

Comment: @MansiChaudhari can you create sqlfiddle demo??

Comment: @MansiChaudhari I had tried with my data..
It's responding properly.